# Bash misinterpreting a sed statement to rename files

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sed, files

I would like to rename a series of files named this way

```
name (10).ext
name (11).ext
...
```

to

```
name_10.ext
name_11.ext
...
```

This one-liner works:

```
$ for i in name\ \(* ; do echo "$i" | sed -e 's! (\([0-9]\{2\}\))!_\1!' ; done
name_10.ext
name_11.ext
...
```

But this one doesn't:

```
$ for i in name\ \(* ; do mv "$i" "$(echo "$i" | sed -e 's! (\([0-9]\{2\}\))!_\1!')" ; done
bash: !_\1!': event not found
```

Why? How to avoid this?

---

Using

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, versione 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

on Ubuntu 18.04.

---

While in this [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33339/cant-use-exclamation-mark-in-bash) a simple case with `!` is shown, here a `!` just inside single quotes is considered and compared to a `!` inside single quotes, inside double quotes. As pointed out in the comments, Bash behaves in a different way in these two cases. This is about Bash version `4.3.48(1)`; this problem seems instead to be no more present in `4.4.12(1)` (it is however recommended to avoid this one-liner, because the Bash version may be unknown in some cases).

As suggested in the Kusalananda answer, if the `sed` delimiter `!` is replaced with `#`,

```
$ for i in name\ \(* ; do mv "$i" "$(echo "$i" | sed -e 's# (\([0-9]\{2\}\))#_\1#')" ; done
```

this problem does not arise at all.

Comment: Bounty for any one that can explain why. I am struggling with this. I have never had a problem, until trying to reproduce this. Some how the outer double quotes disable the inner single quotes, even though the inner quotes are in a sub-shell (). Can you enlighten.

Comment: Hmm... there does seem to be a difference in behavior here between bash 4.3.48 and bash 4.4.19 using a simple test `echo "$(echo '!foo')"`. I wonder if 4.3 is erroneously applying the "single quotes lose their special meaning inside double quotes" rule even when the former are within a command substitution?

Comment: @steeldriver seems correct. I have not looked at the bug tracker, but version 4.4.12(1) seems to get it correct. Better to avoid for a few years, as there will me plenty of all bash around for a bit. steeldriver write-up in an answer, and send me a reminder, when I can set the bounty in a few days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When used in an interactive shell, the `!` may initiate history expansion (not an issue in scripts).

The solution is to use another delimiter than `!` in the `sed` expression.

An alternative `bash` loop:

```
for name in "name ("*").ext"; do
    if [[ "$name" =~ (.*)" ("([^\)]+)").ext" ]]; then
        newname="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_${BASH_REMATCH[2]}.ext"
        printf 'Would move %s to %s\n' "$name" "$newname"
        # mv -i "$name" "$newname"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Ok! Thanks. But, out of curiosity: why does the first one-liner work, then? It contains `!` as well.

Comment: I am struggling with this. I have never had a problem, until trying to reproduce this. Some how the outer double quotes disable the inner single quotes, even though the inner quotes are in a sub-shell `()`. Can you enlighten.

Comment: @BowPark The parsing of history expansion expressions is a bit of a mystery to me, and it seems to not obey ordinary quoting rules. In the first command, the `!` occurs in a single-quoted string. That's the case in the second command as well, but that is included inside a double-quoted string (not taking the fact that there _should_ not be a an issue since the single quoted `!` is in a command substitution).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Yeah. History expansions in `bash` hos always been a bit of a black box to me. It's the quotes. The parsing of the history expansion does not seem to obey normal scoping rules.

Comment: Better: `set +H` to disable this hideous bash misfeature. Add it to your `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Larry Wall's `rename` command (`rename` package in Debian, `prename` in RedHat): it uses the (much easier IMHO) Perl regex syntax, and will iterate the file args (no need to code a loop):

```
rename 's/ \(\d+\)/_$1/' name\ *
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems very convenient. I wonder, however, if it is portable to other *nix systems (not only Linux).

Comment: It is possible, just install it. It is a purl script. It has no dependencies on Linux (the kernel). However beware that there are other commands with the name `rename`, they are not the same. Some Unixes (including those using Linux), have another `rename` installed.

Comment: Available wherever you have Perl, which is about any Unix system. On my Ubuntu I have `prename`installed as part of the Perl package, and `rename` installed as stand-alone (not exactly the same code, even though the core is identical). On Redhat and derivatives there is already a (less powerfull, but easier) `rename` command, so you only have `prename`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the exact range, you can rename the files like this:

```
for i in {10..99}; do mv "name ($i).ext" "name_$i.ext"; done
```

Or, if you want to be POSIX-pedantic:

```
for i in `seq 10 99`; do mv "name ($i).ext" "name_$i.ext"; done
```