# Can I make leading exclamation points be ignored in the terminal? (I type them by instinct due to ipython)

Tags: bash, command-line

Because I spend most of my life in the IPython shell, I have a bad habit of prepending terminal commands with exclamation points. Usually, this just leads to an error, but sometimes, it causes something bad to happen. Can I effectively disable the `!` functionality in my terminal? And would this risk interfering with any scripts?

Comment: I spend most my _life_ In SQL*Plus and use `!` to invoke a shell command; so I frequently when back in the shell hit `!` by mistake!

Comment: You can find a workaround that works on your machine, but keeping this bad habit might bite you when you are using a shell on another computer. Maybe you should consider remapping `!` to give you an electric shock when you type it in Bash; this would be an excellent way to get you rid of that habit in the first place... :)

Comment: Could you clarify, please, whether you type just an exclamation mark, or an exclamation mark plus a space? It seems to matter for the [most upvoted answer at present](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/555747/1982). If you're used to just typing `!` followed by the command (`!ls` or whatever), would typing `! ls` instead work for you (both in shells and IPython shell)?

Comment: Why don't you  run a `%rehashx` in your ipython profile file or first thing in your ipython session so you can avoid the`!` prefixing in the first place

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In interactive shells, by default, `!` is used for history expansion: the shell will look for a command matching the text following `!`, and execute that. As indicated in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33341/86440) to [Can't use exclamation mark (!) in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33339/86440) shells allow history expansion to be disabled:

- Bash: `set +H`
- Zsh: `set -K`

If you never want to use history expansion driven by exclamation marks, you can add these to your shell’s startup scripts.

These won’t cause `!` to be ignored, but they will avoid running commands from your history. `!command` will complain that `!command` doesn’t exist.

Shell scripts aren’t affected by these settings, they get their own shells with a non-interactive configuration (which doesn’t include history expansion by default).

Comment: If I do `set +H` in Bash and then try (for instance) `!ls`, I get an error saying that the command `!ls` wasn't found. `! ls` (with the space) works, but the question seems to suggest the OP is only using `!`, not `!<space>`.

Comment: @T.J. right, this doesn’t cause `!` to be *ignored* entirely, it only ensures that it doesn’t run anything from the history. `! ls` (with a space) is a valid shell expression, it runs `ls` then “negates” its exit code.

Answer (score 19):

If you never use ! from the terminal, you can assign it to a function you also never use, like (in my case) werase:

```bsh
stty werase !
```

Then whenever you type ! , it will just erase the previous word. If you only ever type it at the start of a terminal command, then this will simply have no effect.

If you ever need an actual exclamation point, you can still enter it by preceding it with CTRL-V (or whatever your `lnext` character is) to quote it / escape it.

If you don't normally use the `lnext` functionality, you might find it more convenient to redefine `lnext` to be `!` instead; that would allow you to enter an exclamation point by entering it twice (the first one quoting the second).

```bsh
stty lnext !
```

A more detailed explanation of how this works:

The `lnext` functionality is: "do not interpret the next character as anything special: just accept the character as an input just as it is". If it is an stty special character, then do not apply that special functionality, but just use the character as itself. This includes the character assigned to the `lnext` function.

The default `lnext` character is CTRL-V (mnemonic: "verbatim", as in: enter the next character verbatim). Here, we reassign that function to the character `!` instead.

`lnext` is chosen primarily because its effect is "no effect" for most cases (e.g., when the next character typed is a normal character). When you accidentally type `!` at the start of the line, the next character is almost always a normal character, with no special action, so quoting/escaping it (treating it explicitly as a normal character) does no harm. When we write an `a` after an `!`, the meaning changes from "write an `a`" to the a more specific meaning that does the same.: "write an `a`, an ignore anything else, just do it!"

If we want to create an actual `!` character, we can use that `lnext` functionality to quote it. So, by typing `!!`, a single `!` is entered.

Comment: Note that this will also take effect inside cooked-mode interfaces, like `python` or `ed`.

Comment: Great suggestion, I think `lnext` would be even better. If you then want a real !, just type !!

Comment: `lnext` will enter the next character quoted

Comment: @IMSoP I do not know more than you: I only copied the description line from the man page of `stty`, sorry for implying to have knowledge I do not have. I'll try to come up with a better description.

Comment: @IMSoP I edited the answer explaining how that lnext mechanism works.

Comment: "Quoting" in this context means "keeping as-is". As per the section @IMSoP cited, this just means the character you type after the `lnext` character is kept as-is and not interpreted. If the next character wasn't a special character anyway, it would simply appear as normal (the `lnext` character having no effect in this case).

Comment: `lnext` is pretty much the only way I can type tabs in the terminal (for `sed`).

Answer (score 5):

If using the `zsh` shell, you could add to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
zmodload zsh/zselect
bang() {
  zle self-insert
  if [[ $CONTEXT = start && $LBUFFER =~ '^!+$' ]]; then
    local -a old_region_highlight=($region_highlight)
    region_highlight+=("0 $CURSOR fg=red,bg=white,bold,standout")
    zle -R 'Will you please stop?!'
    zselect -t 100 -r 0 < /dev/tty
    region_highlight=($old_region_highlight)
    LBUFFER=
  fi
}
zle -N bang
bindkey '!' bang
```

So that when you enter one or more `!` at the beginning of the editing buffer, it highlights them in red, gives you a message and removes them (after one second, or sooner if you type anything else).