# Event not found in shell expansion

Tags: zsh, kali-linux, wildcards

```
$ touch fux fax fix
$ ls f[!a]x
zsh: event not found: a]x
```

I want to see fix and fux as output, but not fax.

I want to know the exact reason behind this issue. Is this particular issue regarding the code or not?

Comment: The old curse of history expansion! Almost nobody ever uses it, but almost everyone sometimes gets confused by it. `setopt nobanghist` in everybody's default `~/.zshrc` would make this world a happier place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments from OP have explained that they are looking to match all files OTHER than `fax`.

This can be fixed with [`shopt -s extglob`](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing) (See [Exclude one pattern from glob match](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164025/exclude-one-pattern-from-glob-match))

```bsh
$ touch fix fax fux
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls f!(a)x
fix  fux
```

Alternate answer from Giles (comment below) that does not require `extglob` to be set:

```bsh
$ ls f[^a]x
fix fux
```

My original answer text is below. This answer was written under the assumption he was attempting to use an exclamation point in his answer. After learning from what was stated in OP's comment on my answer, I have reviewed it and added the answer he was looking for above.

The `!` represents a history lookup. See [Can't use exclamation mark (!) in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33339/cant-use-exclamation-mark-in-bash) Your shell will look for the last command that started with:

```bsh
a]x
```

But there is not a command that starts with `a]x`.

Try escaping the exclamation point:

```bsh
$ touch fix fax fux
$ ls f[\!a]x
fix  fux
```

Comment: i need fix and fux as output but ur code gives me fax

Comment: @midhunmohan I have added to my answer explaining how to solve your problem. If it works, please accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark.

Comment: Why go through such complicated lengths? The simple solution is to use `f[^a]x`. Unlike other sh-like shells, zsh supports `^` at the beginning of a character set to take the complement of the set.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I was under the impression that `^` represented "this character is at the beginning of the line". However, I see that I was wrong. Blame the coffee not kicking in early enough ;)

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', is it that common to _not_ support `[^a]`? As far as I tested, Bash, Dash, ksh, Busybox, and yash all support it too; mksh was the one sh-like I found that didn't seem to. (Fish doesn't seem to support either)

Comment: @blackbrandt, note that the question was tagged with [tag:zsh], while `shopt -s extglob` is a Bash feature. The zsh equivalent to `f!(a)x` would be `f(^a)x` (I think), with `setopt extendedglob`. Zsh would support the former too with `setopt kshglob`. Though note that that would also match things like `fx` and `foox`. OTOH, `f[\!a]x` seems to work in zsh, but not in Bash.

Comment: @ilkkachu I thought it was more common, but indeed it isn't. POSIX requires `!` to work and leaves `^` unspecified.