# Environment variables not being set correctly in .bashrc

Tags: linux

I edited my `.bashrc` file, as shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t0Um.png), by adding the following lines

```
TEST='123'
export TEST
```

However, I am not getting any output, when I run `echo $TEST`. It outputs nothing - just an empty line and goes back to the prompt

I want to know the reason why it is like this.

Comment: What shell are you using? What Linux are you using?

Answer (score 2):

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

should get it working. Or alternately you can log out and back in.

Comment: still not working

Comment: Show exactly what you typed. How do you know it isn't working?

Comment: u said me to log out and then log back again i tried that

Comment: when i run this "echo $TEST"  it ouputs nothing just an empty line and gets back to promt

Comment: Use the command I gave you.

Comment: @GraceThompson You don't know if the user is actually using `bash`.  If they are on a recent Kali Linux, then they are using `zsh`.

Comment: Maybe Try `echo $SHELL $shell`.

Comment: According to their previous question, they are indeed using zsh: [Event not found in shell expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/666862/97255)