# How to negate pattern when using awk with double quotes

Tags: bash, awk, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the following file:

```bash
$ cat files
foo.txt
bar.js
```

I am looking to use bash awk to only print files not ending with `.js`.

This works fine when using single quoted awk:

```bash
$ awk '$1 !~ /.js$/ {print $1}' files
foo.txt
```

However, when using double quoted awk:

```bash
$ awk "\$1 !~ /.js$/ {print \$1}" files
-bash: !~: event not found
```

Comment: Why dou want to use double quotes in awk ?

Comment: The environment in which awk is running demands it

Comment: Explain us which env. Windows?

Comment: Is the history expansion actually a problem in that environment, or just in your interactive shell?

Comment: If you use windows, don't use cmd.exe, but PowerShell that allow single quoting

Comment: @GillesQuénot I am using bash in WSL.

Comment: @muru what do you mean?

Comment: If you re in a Linux OS in WSL, use single quotes. If you want to pass variables: `awk -v foo=bar 'BEGIN{print foo}'`

Comment: Why must you use `awk`? It would be easier to use `grep -v '\.js$'`

Comment: @roaima who said I must use awk? I am curious on how I can get this working

Comment: There's no reason at all to use double quotes in awk in Linux

Comment: `awk` and single quotes work perfectly fine for me in WSL.

Comment: @muru I am asking about how to do it with double quotes

Comment: No, you're asking [how to pound in a nail with a glass bottle](https://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925). See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8891/270345. The correct answer is: "***Don't do it.***"

Comment: Using single quotes would be easier also in that you wouldn't need to escape `$` signs, or other double quotes inside the awk script (if you have string constants there). Disabling history expansion would fix the issue with `!`. But if you can't do that either, for whatever reason, you could also rewrite the awk exprassion as `! ($1 ~ /.../)` as `!<space>` doesn't trigger history expansion.

Comment: see also [Can't use exclamation mark (!) in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33339/170373)

Comment: @muru can you explain what the downsides are, aside from readability?

Comment: You already know the downsides - your script is being interpreted by the shell before awk sees it and so you have the problem you're asking about with `!` and you've had to escape `$`s. So we're left with what appears to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as you appear to be asking how to implement something you should never do rather than asking about how to do whatever it is you want to do and so it got downvoted and closed.

Comment: @Foo If you were interested in why you got this error, you got your answer and can ignore the `awk` warriors. If you are interested in how to improve your `awk` coding, I suggest to ask a new question for this. Anyhow, stay happy and move on.

Comment: @Philippos It has certainly been a good reminder as to how toxic this place can be

Comment: @Foo If you have specific issues you want to discuss publicly, please open an issue on our Meta site and explain what you believe is toxic. We don't want this site to be toxic, so anything we can do to improve it would be nice to know.  The Meta site for U&L is available here: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Foo If you want to complain privately about me and how I do moderation, then don't hesitate to contact StackExchange using the contact link at the bottom of any page.  The moderator actions I have taken with regards to this particular question have been: 1) closed the question as a 3rd "voter", 2) cleaned up comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are one of millions to be fooled by *history expansion*, which is active by default, even if only one of a thousand users ever use it.

The best is to disable it in your shell startup file by using `set +H` or `set +o histexpand`. Then you can use `!` without weird problems.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144917/discussion-on-answer-by-philippos-how-to-negate-pattern-when-using-awk-with-doub); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

[**Don't do that**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63263242#63263242).

**With a simple variable argument in [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):**

```bash
$ awk -v exclude='\.js$' '$1 !~ exclude' file
foo.txt
```

Or, import the pattern via the environment (handy way to support patterns containing `\\`):

```bash
$ exclude='\.js$' awk '$1 !~ ENVIRON["exclude"]' file
```

As mentioned in comments (now deleted):

```bash
$ awk "\$1 !""~ /.js$/ {print \$1}" file
```

may work, but it's **not** the recommended way. This is just plain  **ugly**. Learn how to use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) the proper way.